# Can leaving AC on while cooking cause odors to spread around house?

Tags: hvac, smell

From what I understand the central AC sucks in air, the hot air is expelled via the outdoor fan, the cool air is pushed back into the home via the small vents.

So, after it sucks in air (which includes the odor from cooking in the kitchen) is it possible that Some of that odor will reappear in other parts of the house via the small vents?

And do you suggest I NOT have the AC on while cooking, to eliminate the odor from appearing in all the rooms?

Comment: `central AC sucks in air, the hot air is expelled via the outdoor fan` ... incorrect .... the central AC is mounted on the forced air furnace .... it circulates air inside the house .... heat is moved from inside the house to the outside by the use of refrigerant similar to a refrigerator  ....in simple  (and inexact  terms) there is a coil on top of the furnace that gets cold, the warm air inside the house warms up the cold coil (air gets cold) .... the warmed refrigerant inside the coil flows to the outdoor unit where it is cooled again and returned to the top of the furnace

Comment: stop cooking stinky stuff .... lol

Comment: I'm not cooking, it's my mom. And so you're essentially saying that my assumptions were correct? So it is better to NOT leave the ac on while cooking because the odor WILL come back via the vents?

Comment: Or will an Electrostatic furnace filter eliminate any odor from entering the ac unit?

Comment: it might .... i have no experience with electrostatic furnace filters

Comment: Charcoal filters are used for odors but they are fairly expensive for ones that work well. Electrostatic filters will have no effect on odors. Electrostatic filters that actually filter much are also very restrictive to air flow.